# Wordpress Docker NGINX Reverse

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm having issue setting up reverse proxy on my Wordpress docker. I have an Nginx docker container running separately. Using unRAID as the OS. I have other services running under domain.com so I'm trying to run WP in a subdir.

This is the block i'm using in my nginx conf file

```
#Wordpress Docker
location ^~ /blog {
    proxy_pass http://10.0.0.18:91/;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_redirect http://10.0.0.18:91/ https://$host/;
    proxy_cookie_domain http://10.0.0.18:91/ $host;
    include /config/nginx/php.conf;
}
```

When going to domain.com/blog looks like it tries to load but without CSS and only text, for example:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: did you ever figure this out?